# How do I scrape https://www.premierleague.com/players for information about team rosters for the last 10 years?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape data from https://www.premierleague.com/players to get team rosters for premier league clubs for the past 10 years.

The following is the code I am using. In this particular example se=17 specifies season 2008/09 and cl=12 is for Manchester United.

```
url= 'https://www.premierleague.com/players?se=17&cl=12'
r=requests.get(url)
d= pd.read_html(r.text)
d[0]
```

Inspite of the url providing the correct data on the page, the table I get is the one for the current season 2019/20. I have tried multiple combinations of the url and still I am not able to scrape.

Can someone help?

Comment: Try reading the documentation for the `get` method.  You may find that the GET parameters are supplied as a separate argument: `params`.  You can't just pack them into the URL like you do in a browser.  _e.g_ `get('https://www.premierleague.com', params={ 'se': 17, 'cl': 12 })`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `BeautifulSoup` to navigate the DOM. This works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://www.premierleague.com/players", params={"se":17,"cl":12})
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode(), "html.parser")
html = soup.find("div", {"class":"table playerIndex"}).find("table")
df = pd.read_html(str(html))[0]
```

**sample output**

```
          Player    Position Nationality
  Rolando Aarons  Midfielder     England
   Tammy Abraham     Forward     England
       Che Adams     Forward     England
 Dennis Adeniran  Midfielder     England
          Adrián  Goalkeeper       Spain
    Adrien Silva  Midfielder    Portugal
```

Comment: This is the same result I am getting. This list is still for players from 2019/20 season and don't belong to any particular team. I am trying to get team-wise data for all seasons.

Comment: I'm not an EPL fan so wouldn't know....  if it is on page when queried with browser you need to find a) what's the parent HTML element so it can be extracted b) is it a dynamic table built with javascript hence you will need to use a javascript enabled scraping tech like `selenium`.  ONLY static HTML content can be extracted using beautiful soup or pandas